# Would a silicone mat (not anti-static) placed on a truly ESD anti-static mat become anti-static?

Tags: antistatic, equipment

It's just like another component placed on the anti-static mat, right? This should work at providing an inexpensive heat-resistant and anti-static workbench area?

All the 'anti-static' heat resistant mats I found explain in the comments about how they are not really anti-static. And all the inexpensive, true EDS, anti-static mats are not heat resistant. (I'm sure there is one out there that has both, but it's likely out of my price range.)

Therefore, placing a $20 heat resistant mat on a $20 EDS anti-static mat would be the ideal choice? Is there something I'm not considering?

Comment: Your standard *rubber* ESD mat is heat resistant, but yes they tend to be pricey. You can use wood as a cheap alternative (not plywood). Or maybe a thin piece of wood on top of a metal plate.

Comment: Place a cat on top of an ESD mat, then pet the cat for a while. You'll build up a charge still. The word anti-static is unfortunate, because in case of ESD equipment it means "doesn't generate ESD in itself" and not "magically removes static charges occurring in other equipment".

Comment: This ESD mat is within your $40 budget. Cut smaller than your normal sized bench mat for use in trays, but it's the real deal. https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Desco/66126?qs=HePqyd4havIsNcPtRl6wAQ%3D%3D Do not forget the ground kit which is separate since it doesn't come with one (being meant for use in trays)

Comment: @DKNguyen My price range is just less than hundreds of dollars. Since  your first reply, I found this nice $45 all-in-one: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/bertech/2059T-18X24GNKT/11680735

Comment: @adamaero you can't really call that one "heat resistant"

Comment: @jsotola Given the listing is 190F, which is only 88C I would agree. On the other hand, the good Desco ESD mats don't have their temperature listed at all so I have nothing to compare with. Since brief contact with an iron is a fairly variable scenario.

Comment: Their slightly thinner mat (1.52 mm vs 2.03 mm) says 140F to 210F. So I'm guessing 190 is an average: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/bertech/2059S-18X24GNKT/11680809 The "high temperature" one may be 240ish degree F? Probably not since the surface is the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it would not.

There's no conductive path through the silicone mat, so all having a proper one underneath it does is create a weak capacitor to ground, which doesn't help you.